# my touchpad isn't working please help me!

Tags: xubuntu, touchpad, xfce, lts, 20.04

My touchpad doesn't work. It used to work when I used Elementary OS before. I have now installed Xubuntu 20.04. But my touchpad didn't work. But my USB mouse is working. What can I do?

Comment: Start by running `lsusb` and edit your question with the results.

Comment: @ToDo `lsusb` won't show anything related to a touchpad.

Comment: Please add output of `xinput` to your question.

Comment: Do you have errors in output of `dmesg | grep psmouse`? Does it work before you log in? Can you check if it works in `openbox` session?